# How to retrieve all the nodes of an xml using xml::libxml in perl?

Tags: xml, perl

I have an xml file like this "file.xml

```
  <tables>
        <table>
                <name>abc</name>
                <row>12</row>
                <col>13</col>
        <table>
                <name>xyz</name>
                <IsWrapper/>
            <table>
                      <name>dummy</name>
                       <row>121</row>
                       <col>131</col>
            </table>
        </table>        
    </tables>

    I am using xml::libxml using perl. Here is the code.

# ----- Parsing config XML file ---
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xmldoc = $parser->parse_file ("file.xml") || die("Could not parse xml file\n");
my $root = $xmldoc->getDocumentElement()|| die("Could not get Document Element \n");
print "\n root = $root \n";
if ($root->nodeType == ELEMENT_NODE) 
    {

        foreach my $child ($root->getChildNodes()) 
        { 
            #print "\n my child: $child \n";
            $st = $child->textContent;
            print "\n child name: $st \n";
            if ($child->nodeName eq 'table')
            {  
                $dc = $child->nodeName;
                print "\n node name is node: $dc\n";
                if (defined($child->getElementsByTagName('IsWrapper',0)->item(0)))
                { 
                    #do some thing
                }
                else
                {   
                    print "\n eneterd in else part\n";
                    #do some thing        
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But i am not able to get the main node. I am able to get only this structure.

```
<table>
            <name>xyz</name>
            <IsWrapper/>
        <table>
                  <name>dummy</name>
                   <row>121</row>
                   <col>131</col>
        </table>
    </table>
```

How can i get all the elements in the structure in the same order.

The output should be like this

```
<tables>
<table><name>abc</name>
    <row>12</row>
    <col>13</col>
    <name>xyz</name>
        <row>121</row>
    <col>131</col>
        </table>
 </tables>
```

How can i parse the above XML and get the below output in libxml using Perl?

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This not a [well-formed](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-wellformed) XML document.
You have got three opening table tags and only two closing.

You should check your XML Code with a [XML-Validator](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_validator.asp) first.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with AlexTheBird.

If you change the xml for a valid stat, you will able to parse the file.
This file:

```
<tables>
    <table>
        <name>abc</name>
        <row>12</row>
        <col>13</col>
    </table>
</tables>
```

Give me the follow result, using XML::Simple

```
$VAR1 = {
      'table' => {
                 'col' => '13',
                 'row' => '12',
                 'name' => 'abc'
               }
    };
```

Comment: ok ok.... but how will proceed further with getting all nodes because the reference is file.xml so the below output. Please let me know how to proceed with xml::libxml in getting all the nodes.

Comment: If a XML document is not well formed than it isn't a XML document and so it can not be treated as an XML document. Tell the people who created this to learn something about XML or not using it because well formedness is a MUST when you work with XML-Parsers. I guess you have to write you own parser for this broken XML.